# Date format in a list is changed into numbers

Tags: r

I have a start date and an end date but when I am making a list to contain all dates in between, the format is changed:

```
> startDate <- as.Date("2012-01-01")
> startDate
[1] "2012-01-01"
> endDate <- as.Date("2012-02-01")
> endDate
[1] "2012-02-01"
> startDate:endDate
[1] 15340 15341 15342 15343 15344 15345 15346 15347 15348 15349 15350 15351 15352 15353 15354 15355
[17] 15356 15357 15358 15359 15360 15361 15362 15363 15364 15365 15366 15367 15368 15369 15370 15371
```

So you can see that all dates are converted to a numeric format.
But the problem is, I have a API function that can only read date format as "YYYY-MM-DD".
Can any one suggest how I can generate such a list like:

```
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `seq` function:

```
seq(startDate,endDate,by="day") #you could use also by=1
# see ?seq.Date for other options for "by"
```

From help page of operator `:` (use `?":"` or `?Colon`):

> For other arguments from:to is equivalent to seq(from, to), and
>   generates a sequence from from to to in steps of 1 or -1. Value to
>   will be included if it differs from from by an integer up to a numeric
>   fuzz of about 1e-7. Non-numeric arguments are coerced internally
>   (hence without dispatching methods) to numeric—complex values will
>   have their imaginary parts discarded with a warning.

So

```
identical(startDate:endDate,as.numeric(startDate):as.numeric(endDate))
[1] TRUE
```

And btw, you are generating a vector, not a list. You can make a list out of your values by using `as.list` function though, if that is what you really want.